# Bootstrap with two static sections

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I'm creating a mobile site using bootstrap and i'm struggling to get the CSS correct. 
I am trying to create 3 sections on the page.
Navigation - this will always be at the top, so when the page scrolls, the navbar is always visible. Im using the standard bootstrap navbar for this and appears to work well.
I next have a DIV which display a pretty line graph - i would like this to be the same as the nav bar - i.e. does not scroll away.
Next i have a DIV which contains a table, this needs to be scrollable.

So essentially the top half of the screen should just be static and the bottom half containing the grid should move. This is what i've done so far! but it doesn't seem correct.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
</nav>

<div style="padding-top:70px; z-index:100; height:430px; top:0; position:absolute; padding-right:2%">
A pretty line Graph
</div>

<div style="position:relative; height:100%; overflow-y:auto; overflow-x: hidden; padding-top:430px;">
My Table
```

Hopefully that makes sense.....

Comment: wrap all 3 with another div, <div style=" position:fixed; top:0; left:0; height:100px; width:100%;">your 3 tags here<\div>, change the height to what ever :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    Place your header items here
</nav>
<div class="page-header">
    Place your chart here
</div>

<div class="container">
    Place your table here
</div>
```

CSS:
body { padding-top: 70px; }